# Update .py file on nginx, gunicorn, supervisor

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I don't know why this is so difficult, but everytime I update a file in my flask application I have to restart gunicorn so that the file updates on the server. I am mostly a front-end developer and don't play with servers enough to remember these things, and I have to spend hours google searching various phrases to find the right commands. This time I can't seam to find anything, and the file I created to save these things has conveniently disappeared.

My server:
Ubuntu 18.04
nginx
gunicorn
supervisor

I am updating a .py file. I placed the updated version on the server using ftp. I'm logged into the server, using ssh, through a git bash shell. `sudo systemctl gunicorn restart` give me the error `Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.`. Rereading and restarting supervisor does not do the trick, and neither does restarting nginx. Is there not a simple command to apply updates? I'm use to using servers on general hosting sites, and updating a file via ftp just works. I was really enjoying learning flask up until this point, but now I regret it. I keep thinking that there has to be some kind of simple trick to make such a simple thing go smoothly, but I'm at the end of my rope trying to figure this out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.

```
sudo supervisorctl stop app_name
sudo supervisorctl start app_name
```